# Count passed arguments to a method

Tags: java, arrays

is there a possibility in java to count the number of passed arguments into a method?

Got something like this:

```
public class practise7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array3 = new int[]{1};
        int[] array4 = new int[]{1, 3, 4};
        int[] array5 = new int[]{2, 3,};

        combine(array3, array4, array5);
        
    }
   
    public static void combine(int[] array3, int[] array4, int[] array5) {
        //Here i need the number of passed arguments (here 3 e.g.)

        int count = args.length; //found this on google but didn't worked
        System.out.println(count);
        
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It uses the var...arg syntax.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array3 = new int[]{1};
        int[] array4 = new int[]{1, 3, 4};
        int[] array5 = new int[]{2, 3,};

        combine(array3, array4, array5);
        
    }
   // uses the variable arguments syntax
    public static void combine(int[]...v) {
        //Here i need the number of passed arguments (here 3 e.g.)

        int count = v.length; 
        System.out.println(count);

        for (int[] k : v) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
3
[1]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 3]
```

Note that combining arrays and non-arrays in the argument list can sometimes provide unexpected results. The variable syntax argument must be the last one in the signature.

Comment: Worked - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work because with 'args.length' you can only get the number of arguments that were passed in the main function. You can use variable arugments feature of Java as follows:

```
public static void combine(int[] ... arrays) 
{
        int count = arrays.length;
        System.out.println(count);
}
```